# How do I create a condition from a variable value that I have?

Tags: javascript

I have set a cookie with a name and value.

```
function getCookie(cname)
    {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');

        for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++)
            {
                var c = ca[i];

                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
                    {
                        c = c.substring(1);
                    }

                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0)
                    {
                        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                    }
            }
        return "";
    }

var cookieName = getCookie("name1");
```

I'm getting its value in cookieName.

Now, I want to do something if the value of cookieName is say 'abc'.

How do I make the if statemet for this case?

I've tried:

```
if (cookieName == 'abc')
    {
        console.log(cookieName);
    }
```

and this doesn't work.

Comment: For debugging purposes, what does the console log say if you take away the if statement?

Comment: @james It shows the required value if I put the console.log outside the if statement.

Comment: Can you try if(cookieName === 'abc')

Comment: Your code is a little confusing because `cookieName` actually returns the *value* of the cookie whose name is `name1`. It might be clearer to use the variable `cookieValue` instead of `cookieName`.

Comment: @james Yeah! That's it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TobyRush Yeah, I am changing it now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments, try a triple equals.

```
if (cookieName === 'abc')
{
    console.log(cookieName);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Answer (score 0):

You can view the cookies you've set in the developer console (chrome).
If you don't see the cookie there ('abc'), you may not be setting a proper expiration date on the cookie. Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I can see the cookie there and also read the value. I have correctly set the cookie. Now, I need to do something if the cookie has a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @james in comments, only a small change was required.

The new if statement looks like:

```
if (cookieName === 'abc')
    {
        console.log(cookieName);
    }
```